# Why does this code create two objects while one is needed?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a tutorial code for Qt:

Header file:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Notepad;
}

class Notepad : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Notepad(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Notepad();

private:
    Ui::Notepad *ui;
};
```

Source file:

```
#include "notepad.h"
#include "ui_notepad.h"

Notepad::Notepad(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Notepad)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Notepad::~Notepad()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And in main,

```
#include "notepad.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Notepad w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

So when we do `Notepad w`, an object is already created on the stack, and why does the code still create another object on the heap using new and assign to a member?

Comment: Is this not your code? In constructor you have this ...ui(new Ui::Notepad), then of course heap memory allocated...should it not?

Comment: There should be an instance of Notepad::Notepad, and UI::Notepad.  No more from the looks of it.

Comment: initiation list, slightly different than the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one on the stack is of type `Notepad`, and it's the application's main window. The dynamic one is of type `Ui::Notepad`. That's a class automatically generated by Qt's `uic` tool; it contains the widgets created in UI creator as data members.

In a way, you could say that `Notepad` is concerned with the logic and uses an instance of `Ui::Notepad` to provide the GUI for it.

Comment: Oh I was wondering why `notepad.h` and `ui_notepad.h` are there.. Now it makes sense! It is really confusing when 2 classes have the same name but in different namespaces!